# std::map<x,y>: How to declare array of struct (y) inside a map function

Tags: c++, stdmap

I want to declare n array of struct inside a map function. The code snippet is below, it is throwing me an error while i tried to do m_channelInfo[destination]=newdata[chNum]. And error is, 
" No operator matches "=" operand"  I am confused about how to solve this or I can't use array of struct indie a map function. Please suggest.

```
chNum=10;
struct Record
  {
   int pkt;
   double frameErrorRate;
   double ProbabilityVector;

  };


void ChannelUsageData (Mac48Address destination, Mac48Address retransmitter)
{

  std::map<Mac48Address, Record>::iterator i = m_channelInfo.find (destination); 
  if (i == m_channelInfo.end ())
    {
      Record newdata[chNum];
      // std::vector<Record> newdata;
      //Record newdata;

      m_channelInfo[destination] = newdata;

    }
  i = m_channelInfo.find (destination);
  NS_ASSERT (i != m_channelInfo.end ());

}
```

Comment: Show the definition of `Mac48Address`

Answer (score 0):

declare the `m_channelInfo` as `std::map<Max48Address, Record*>` and have the iterator defined as
`std::map<Mac48Address, Record*>::iterator i`

you'll also need to change your allocation to dynamic array and not static...

```
if (i == m_channelInfo.end ())
{
  Record* newdata = new Record[chNum];

  m_channelInfo[destination] = newdata;

}
```

then you'll be able to assign the value as an array (pointer)
and don't forget to properly delete the memory using `deleted[]` during destuction

Comment: @MattMcNabb: this is not correct, indeed the `newdata` variable will cease to exist, but the pointer value will be copied into the map, therefore the memory will not be lost

Comment: @MattMcNabb: nothing is releasing the dynamic memory at end of block... the user will need to `delete[]` the pointer himself. i don't follow you

Comment: @MattMcNabb: ok, noted... ignore our discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ arrays must have the size known at compile-time. `Record newdata[chNum];` is illegal.  (Some compilers implement this as an extension but it's not really advisable to use it).

It's not clear what you're trying to do here:

```
 m_channelInfo[destination] = newdata;
```

Your map takes a `Mac48Address` , which I presume is a struct of some sort, to a `Record`. It does not make sense to assign a group of Records to a single Record.

Can you describe what you expect the map entries to contain?

Comment: Mac48Address is not a struct, its a bunch of int value as string. And unfortunately there is a typo, it should be m_channelInfo.find (destination) insread of Transmitter. 
I will have multiple destination mac48address, and against each mac address(destination) I need to record data for chNum no of different situations.
The code works if I have only on struct instead of array of struct. But I need a fixed size array of struct as I did.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is `map<Mac48Address, vector<Record> >` then?  Also consider using `multimap` instead.

Comment: ya I tried with vector. It throws same type of error. Initially I thought, error is because of complier does not know the size of struct.

I dont need multimap actually. Single map will do my job and easier I guess.

Comment: Show the code that is giving you the error. Remember you need to use `push_back()` or other vector functions to put items in the vector.